# docker registry v2 : get parent image name

Tags: docker, docker-registry

I would like to get the parent of current image using docker registry api v2. Is it possible ?.

I am trying to construct a tree structure of all docker images with parent/child relationship for which I need parent of each docker image. I can get all repositories using GET /v2/_catalog & manifest for each repository by GET /v2//manifests/latest, but I couldn't figure out how to get parent out of it.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

If you examine the manifest of an image you should see blocks of "v1Compatibility" sections in the JSON output.

If you look at those, you should see base image information. For example when I ran this on one of my images, derived from Centos 7:

```
curl --insecure https://myregistry:5000/v2/imagename/manifests/latest | grep -i centos
```

I see:

```
[...]
"v1Compatibility": "{\"id\":\"172ab63cd5e007f8b1dbd7659c2d9520bf9e50755c081f39d171a603ad5d0890\",\"parent\":\"0c908fa575ec22f872f78b12d9e57d132b67a683f7deacd9f02462c546bf52dd\",\"created\":\"2016-04-01T21:28:21.706982438Z\",\"container_config\":{\"Cmd\":[\"/bin/sh -c #(nop) LABEL name=CentOS Base Image vendor=CentOS license=GPLv2 build-date=2016-03-31\"]}}"
"v1Compatibility": "{\"id\":\"3690474eb5b4b26fdfbd89c6e159e8cc376ca76ef48032a30fa6aafd56337880\",\"created\":\"2015-09-07T19:05:48.678585881Z\",\"container_config\":{\"Cmd\":[\"/bin/sh -c #(nop) MAINTAINER The CentOS Project \\u003ccloud-ops@centos.org\\u003e\"]}}"
[...]
```

Parsing this should give you the information you want.

Comment: In v1Compatibility we have id field which is probably the id of parent image (the last row in the history). But I couldn't figure out how to get the image name using that id.

Comment: I just follow the chain of id and parent identifiers and it is possible to track the chain. But as far as I can see these are layer IDs in reverse chronological order. Meaning the youngest child is on top of the list. So far I haven't found a hash map/correlation, though you can trace the whole history back to the very first scratch image.